# Does SQL Server upgrade affect running replications

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 3 servers with SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer edition. And I have a replication setup between those servers (Transaction & Merge).

If I go to upgrade it to 2008 R2 Standard edition service pack 1, does this affect the current replication setup?

- Current SQL Server version : SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer edition
- Expecting SQL Server version : SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard edition

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/941232

Comment: This is no upgrade. This is an *edition downgrade* of an unsupported version. Developer Edition has all the features of Enterprise, including the ability to perform many operations online. You probably can't even buy 2008 R2

Comment: If you care about upgrading, the minimum supported version is SQL Server 2012. SQL Server 2016 SP1 would be a far better option though, as many features that used to be available only in Enteprise are now available even in Express, eg compression, partitioning, in-memory databases, columnstores

Comment: @TheGameiswar thanks for the answer, but I would like to know if I down grade from Developer to standard, the it will affect in current running replication structure ?

Comment: replication won't be affected ,since there are no features which are available in enterprise for replication,but not in standard.Check out Panagitios comments as well

Comment: Thank you, as I know Peer to peer replication is not supported in standard edition, that I have exclude. And for use of 2016 is management level decesion I can not take that decesion.